Can I put a couple of std::functions with unspecified return type into a container in C++?If so, how to do that?
I want to write a generic sorter in C++. I have some code like this.
  template<typename T>
  class sorter {
  public:

    template<typename R>
    bool RegisterDimValueFetcher(const std::string &name, const std::function<R(const T &)> &f)
    {
      if (!f) {
        return false;
      }

      bool inserted = fetcher_map.insert(std::make_pair(name, f)).second;
      if (inserted) {
        priority_list.emplace_back(name);
      }
      return inserted;
    }

    bool AdjustPriority(const std::vector<std::string> &priorityList) {
      priority_list.assign(priorityList.begin(), priorityList.end());
      return priority_list == priorityList;
    }

    template<template<typename...> class C>
    bool sort(C<T> &collection, bool asc = true, typename std::enable_if<is_container<C<T>>::value>::type* = nullptr) {

      std::sort(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [&](const T &lRef, const T &rRef) {

        for (auto &dim : priority_list) {
          auto pair_iter = fetcher_map.find(dim);
          if (pair_iter != fetcher_map.end()
              && pair_iter->second) {

            auto l_val = pair_iter->second(lRef);
            auto r_val = pair_iter->second(rRef);

            if (l_val != r_val) {
              return asc ? std::less<R>()(l_val, r_val) : std::less<R>()(r_val, l_val);  // here using the template type R and it's obviously wrong.
            }
          }
        }
        return true;
      });
      return true;
    }

  private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<R(const T &)>> fetcher_map; // template type R is not declared, but if it declared, current class could not support different return type
    std::vector<std::string> priority_list;

  };

I want this code to meet my expectation with usage code like this:
struct Student {
  Student(const std::string &stuName, size_t stuAge)
    : name(stuName), age(stuAge) { }
  Student(const Student &ref)
    : name(ref.name), age(ref.age) { }

  std::string name;
  size_t age;
};

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, Student &stu) {
  os << "{name:" << stu.name << ", age:" << stu.age << "]";
  return os;
}

int func() {

  std::vector<Student> students;
  students.emplace_back(std::string("n1"), 36u);
  students.emplace_back(std::string("n2"), 36u);
  students.emplace_back(std::string("n2"), 37u);
  students.emplace_back(std::string("n3"), 2u);

  sorter<std::string, Student> gsorter;
  gsorter.RegisterDimValueFetcher("name", [](const Student &stu) {
      return stu.name;
      });
  gsorter.RegisterDimValueFetcher("age", [](const Student &stu) {
      return stu.age;
      //return std::to_string(stu.age);
      });

  gsorter.sort(students, false);
  for (auto &stu : students) {
    std::cout << stu << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  gsorter.AdjustPriority({"age", "name"});

  gsorter.sort(students);
  for (auto &stu : students) {
    std::cout << stu << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}


and got result like content below:
{name:n3, age:2}
{name:n2, age:37}
{name:n2, age:36}
{name:n1, age:36}

{name:n3, age:2}
{name:n1, age:36}
{name:n2, age:36}
{name:n2, age:37}


I tried to make R as a template type declared after template type T, this led to changing of return type to a specified one, like commented line in the second lambda.
Can any one help me improving the code. My expectation is to make the class sorter to be an implementation of keyword 'ORDER BY' in mysql.

there is no efficient way to store std::function<R(const T &)>, the compiler must know what R is, wrost case it could be std::any, a slightly faster object is std::variant, best option is to not store it at all, and instead pass the fetcher as argument to the function, and avoid the over-engineered generality

std::function cannot have an unspecified return type.

FWIW C++ already pretty much has this with the ranges library.  For instance you can to sort by a single member you can use std::ranges::sort(colection, {}, &class_name::member_name);.  If you want to sort by multiple members then make use a helper member like std::ranges::sort(colection, [](const auto& rhs, const auto& lhs) { return std::tie(rhs.mem1, ..., rhs.memN) < std::tie(lhs.mem1, ..., lhs.memN)

You seem to want to use std::variant and std::visit.

"I have some code like this." ... "I want this code to meet my expectation with usage code like this:" -- Don't define functionality with code, unless the code already works perfectly (hence there would be no question). Describe what you want in words, then provide code to demonstrate what you described. This is not just for a better question. Sometimes/often writing out your thoughts makes it clearer what your code should look like.

You might get rid of template return type if you store (three-way) comparers instead of getters:
template<typename T>
class sorter
{
public:

    bool RegisterComparer(const std::string &name,
                          const std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> &f)
    {
      if (!f) {
        return false;
      }

      bool inserted = comparer_map.insert(std::make_pair(name, f)).second;
      if (inserted) {
        priority_list.emplace_back(name);
      }
      return inserted;
    }

    template<template<typename...> class C,
             typename std::enable_if<is_container<C<T>>::value, bool>::type = false >
    bool sort(C<T> &collection, bool asc = true) const {
        std::sort(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [&](const T &lRef, const T &rRef) {
            for (auto &dim : priority_list) {
                auto pair_iter = comparer_map.find(dim);
                if (pair_iter != comparer_map.end() && pair_iter->second) {
                    const auto comp = (pair_iter->second)(lRef, rRef) * (asc ? 1 : -1);
                    if (comp == 0) continue;
                    return comp < 0;
                }
            }
            return false;
      });
      return true;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<int(const T&, const T&)>> comparer_map;
    std::vector<std::string> priority_list;
};

sorter<Student> gsorter;
gsorter.RegisterComparer("name", [](const Student &lhs, const Student &rhs) {
      return lhs.name.compare(rhs.name);
    });
gsorter.RegisterComparer("age", [](const Student &lhs, const Student &rhs) {
      return (int) lhs.age - (int) rhs.age;
    });

Demo
